# Cannot create gcloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, fast-ai

Following https://course.fast.ai/start_gcp.html this set up:

```
export IMAGE_FAMILY="pytorch-latest-gpu" # or "pytorch-latest-cpu" 
for non-GPU instances
export ZONE="us-west2-b" # budget: "us-west1-b"
export INSTANCE_NAME="my-fastai-instance"
export INSTANCE_TYPE="n1-highmem-8" # budget: "n1-highmem-4"

# budget: 'type=nvidia-tesla-k80,count=1'
gcloud compute instances create $INSTANCE_NAME \
        --zone=$ZONE \
        --image-family=$IMAGE_FAMILY \
        --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
        --maintenance-policy=TERMINATE \
        --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1" \
        --machine-type=$INSTANCE_TYPE \
        --boot-disk-size=200GB \
        --metadata="install-nvidia-driver=True" \
        --preemptible
```

Got this error:

`(gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/xxxxxx/zones/us-west2-b/acceleratorTypes/nvidia-tesla-p100' was not found`

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried replicating the same steps you followed from the tutorial and got the same error.

According to **[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#gpus-list)**, **NVIDIA-TESLA-P100** is only available in these zones:

> - us-west1-a
> - us-west1-b
> - us-central1-c
> - us-central1-f
> - us-east1-b
> - us-east1-c
> - europe-west1-b
> - europe-west1-d
> - europe-west4-a
> - asia-east1-a
> - asia-east1-c
> - australia-southeast1-c

And you may have selected **us-west2-b, which is not available.**
Therefore, I would just change your zone to one of the previously mentioned ones.

To get this list in a more programmatic way, using [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/accelerator-types/list) for example, you could issue:

```
gcloud compute accelerator-types list --filter "name=nvidia-tesla-p100" --format "table[box,title=Zones](zone:sort=1)" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are reporting is caused because this GPU is not available in the zone “us-west2-b”, you can review where GPU you can use in this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#gpus-list).

In this case, according at the region you are using, you can use in:

- us-west1-a
- us-west1-b

Regards.